# Why Java 8 compilation fails when Default Method is overridden by subclass's Static Method?

Tags: java, interface

Given Java 8, why the code bellow fails to compile?

```
interface Father {
    static void method() { }
}

interface Mother {
    default void method() { }
}

interface Child extends Father, Mother {
    static void method() { }
}
```

Per my understanding, each static method belongs to its specific Class, hence, why when Child interface defines `static void method() { }` the compiler gives the following error?

> method() in Child clashes with method() in Mother overriding method is static

Should not Child keep the default method implementation from Mother while allowing Father and Child with its own Static methods like: 
Father.method() and Child.method() ?

Comment: The problem is that `Child` extends `Mother` which has a non-static method, named `method`.  Defining another method in `Child` with the same name and signature (even if it differs in static/non-static) is not allowed.

Comment: Do you know why it is not allowed? I don't see the reason why it should not be, as a static method is defined in the context of a Class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Father` is not a problem here since *static methods from interfaces are **not inherited*** (for instance `List.of(..)` can't be invoked via `ArrayList.of(..)`) so there is no overriding/hiding which also means no collisions.

Because of that we can safely write

```
interface Father {
    static void method() { } 
}
interface Child extends Father {
    static void method() { } 
}
```

**Problem** is `default void method() { }` method from `Mother` interface which is inherited to `Child` which means that after

```
interface Child extends Father, Mother { 
    static void method() { } 
}
```

you would end up with interface which would have two `method()` versions: static and non-static (default)

```
interface Child extends Father, Mother { 
    static void method() { } 
    default void method() { } //inherited from Mother
}
```

**But why is that a problem?**

Imagine you want to add another method to `Child` interface which will call `method()`

```
interface Child extends Father, Mother { 
    static void method() { } 
    default void method() { } //inherited from Mother
    default void demo(){
        method(); //which code block should be executed?
    }
}
```

Should it execute code from *static* method() or from *default* method()? Compiler wouldn't be able to decide.

Although this situation could be solved by using

- `Child.method()` for static method,
- `this.method()` for default method (yes, it wound't be ambiguous because static method wouldn't be inherited by class of which `this` would be instance),

point is to prevent such problems in the first place. That is why we are required to not have static and non-static methods with same signature (name+parameterTypes) in one place (defined or inherited).

Answer (score 1):

It's an interesting situation. I think the simple answer is that static methods have never been allow to **hide** (they can't override) non-static methods in base classes. If you remove the `static` modifier from `Father`, that would also cause Child not to compile. This is probably to avoid confusion.

So default methods just followed that existing rule.

"But hold on", you might think, "default methods were added with the explicit intent to allow library developers introduce new functionality into old interfaces without breaking existing code. If any existing code had a static method with a clashing name - wouldn't it break?"

Actually I think it doesn't. IIRC, this is a place where binary compatibility & source compatibility are intentionally allowed to differ. I think you would find that if:

- `interface Child` (and stuff using it) had already been compiled while that default method wasn't present in `interface Mother`, and
- you later added the default method to `interface Mother` and compiled **only** that source file.

Then I think you'd end up with the code given working just fine (at the bytecode / JVM level). It would however break at compile-time at the point you tried to *recompile* `interface Child` against the updated `interface Mother`.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) which explains more cases.

Basically here you can find a summary (extracted from the tutorial):

[image: Defining a Method with the Same Signature as a Superclass's Method]